# Migrating from ECS to K8s impact on Gitlab pipelines

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci, amazon-ecs, kops

We’re using Gitlab as our main DevOps tool, and the infrastructure is on AWS ECS cluster (all Gitlab pipelines are pushing to the cluster instances).

Now we are planning to migrate from AWS ECS to Kubernetes (using K8s Kops on AWS, not EKS), and would like to know the IMPACT on the pipelines (how we can implement the migration with the minimal downtime on the CI process).

Thanks,
Ali

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the specific problems in your current plan?

Comment: I believe this question is better answered 1:1 rather than here. I suggest you ping me at hausenbl@amazon.com and we take it from there. Once you've done the migration, you might want to come back here and answer the question yourself, benefiting everyone else who comes after you. Deal?